# Bootstrap Centering Content within a Div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Basically I want my drop down boxes to be horizontally aligned in the center of the `<div>`. Currently they are in a column and inside a `<div>` which has displayed them vertically, by default and has pushed the content to the left of the `<div>`.

[image]

I'm using the latest version of bootstrap and only have CSS to pad the header and to set it as transparent!

```
<div class=" navbar  transparent navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation"> <!--HEADER-->
        <div class="container-fluid header">                                                    <!--CONTAINER- Needs to be inset slightly-->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>


                <!--First NavBar Colum - Logo is Located Here-->
                <div class=" navbar-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="col-sm-4 ">

                        </div>

                <!--Second NavBar Colum - Centered Horizontal Navigation Links are Located Here-->
                    <div class="col-sm-4 ">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                            <ul class="dropdown">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>
                                <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">PLAY</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li class="divider"></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Public Teatimes</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Member Teatimes</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Course Tour</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Rates and Ratings</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Outings</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </ul>

                            <ul class="dropdown">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>
                                <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">CLUB</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li class="divider"></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Membership</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Calender</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Lessons and Shop</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Bar and Food</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </ul>

                            <ul>
                                <i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>
                                <a href="#contact" data-toggle="modal">CONTACT</a>
                            </ul>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                        <!--Third NavBar Colum - Social Media Icons are Located Here-->
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-3x"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-3x"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-instagram fa-3x"></i>


                                </div>



                        </div> <!--/ .nav-collapse-->
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: have you tried `text-align:center`?

Comment: Yes, but it does not appear to center the 'ul dropdowns' in the div

Comment: could you post a fiddle?

Comment: You have invalid code.  `ul`s can only have lis as their children - you have some with nested` `ul`s, `a`s and `i`s as children. But to center your lis, you just need to make them `display:inline-block` elements and add `text-align:center` to the parent

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1nzzvbo7/2/embedded/result/

thats the basics of it, it doesnt appear to show the two other columns, but i guess it may help

Comment: Thanks pete, I knew the code looked off. Will update and get back to you

Answer (score 0):

In `.navbar-nav, .navbar-left` there is `float:left` . SO, you have remove that first `float:none`. Then on parent `col-sm-4` you can add `.text-center`.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
 .navbar-nav{
    width:250px;
    margin:0 auto;
    float:none;
    text-align:center;
    }
```

And remove float from `<li>` if you use.

Answer (score -1):

`@media (min-width: 768px)
.navbar-nav {
text-align: center;}`